# No me funciona el bindParam en sentencia preparada

Tags: php, pdo

No logro remplazar el parámetro por su valor.

En el singleton de conexión uso `PDO`. O, ¿cómo debo hacer? Debo usar los signos de interrogación.

En su lugar me busca en la base de datos como `nombre=:nombre`, lo toma literalmente.

Busqué en la documentación y parece estar todo bien.

Este es el código PHP:

```
public function ingresoUser($usuario,$pass)
{
      if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $usuario) &&
       preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $pass)){
            $encriptar = crypt($pass, 
              '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
        try
        {
            $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();

            $sqluser="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre=:nombre AND pass=:pass";

          $sql=$conexion->prepare($sqluser);
          $sql->bindParam(":nombre",$usuario);
          $sql->bindParam(":pass",$encriptar);

          $sql->execute();

           $array=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $array;        
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es `Conexion.php`:

```
<?php
 class Conexion
 {
private static $instancia;
public $dbh;

protected function __construct()
{
    try {
                $ini ="config.ini" ;
                $parse = parse_ini_file ( $ini , true ) ;

              //  $driver = $parse [ "db_driver" ] ;

                $host = $parse [ "db_host" ] ;

                $port=$parse["db_port"];
                $user = $parse [ "db_user" ] ;
                $password = $parse [ "db_password" ] ;
                $dbname = $parse["db_dbname"];

                $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='. $dbname .';' . 'host=' .$host;
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);

        $this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        return $this->dbh;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();

        die();
    }
}

public function prepare($sql)
{

    return $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

}

  public static function singleton_conexion()
  {

    if (!isset(self::$instancia)) {
        $miclase = __CLASS__;
        self::$instancia = new $miclase;

    }

    return self::$instancia;

}

 static public function closeConnection()
 {
  if (!self::$instance === null) {
     self::$instance = null;
  }
  if (isset(self::$connection)) {
     unset(self::$connection);
  }
 }
 public function query($texto){

     $array=$this->prepare($texto);
     $array->execute();
     $result=$array->fetchAll();
     return $result;

   } 



   public function errorCode() {
    return self::$instancia->errorCode();
   } 
   public function beginTransaction() {
   $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
   }   
    public function rollBack() {
    $this->dbh->rollBack();
   }  
   public function commit() {
    $this->dbh->commit();
  } 


    // Evita que el objeto se pueda clonar
   public function __clone()
   {

    trigger_error('La clonación de este objeto no está permitida', 
    E_USER_ERROR);

     }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Podríamos ver el código de la clase `Conexion` relativa al establecimiento de la conexión? ¿Podrías probar a separar con un espacio en blanco el igual del nombre del campo y de los dos puntos? ¿Cómo sabes que toma las cadenas `:nombre` y `:pass` literalmente? En ese caso generarían una excepción por error sintáctico ([error `#1064`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_parse_error)).

Comment: Hay adjunte el codigo de la clase conexion, los valores los tomo de un .ini.

Comment: @Caruso Intentaste diciendole que tipo de dato le pasaras? Es decir, el tipo de datos explícito para el parámetro. Seria algo como `$sql->bindParam(":nombre",$usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);`

Comment: Dos cosas: ¿Podrías responderme al resto de preguntas que te hice en mi primer comentario? Sobre todo es importante la relativa a cómo sabes que se toma literalmente `:nombre` y `:pass`, lo del espacio entre el igual y los dos puntos y el campo debería ser indiferente, pero por si acaso. Por otro lado, hacer `$this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` es una mala práctica, deberías usar `charset` en el DSN para que PDO sea consciente del juego de caracteres utilizado.

Comment: Con literalmente me referia a que hice un echo de la consulta sql y no cambia los valores de los parametros, busca nombre=:nombre, por ejemplo. Tambien probe separando con un espacio entre los dos puntos y el igual y nada

Comment: Finalmente funciono poniendo el tipo de parametro y la longitud, deberia ver en la documentacion oficial de php si son requeridos. Gracias a los dos

Comment: @Caruso no, no es requerido. PHP rellena los campos no proporcionados con valores por defecto (en el caso del tipo se usa `PDO::PARAM_STR`) y si es necesario recortar la longitud de una cadena para que funcione la consulta entonces se debería haber generado un error en la consulta. Además, lo que sí que te recomiendo es que uses [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](https://www.php.net/es/pdostatement.bindvalue) en vez de [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/es/pdostatement.bindparam) si no vas a reutilizar la consulta preparada en varias iteraciones con diferentes valores.

Comment: Para que errores en las consultas generen una excepción deberías cambiar `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` por `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Así podrás capturar el error con tu bloque `try / catch` y obtener el mensaje de error real relacionado con el problema por el que no se ejecuta correctamente tu instrucción SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias OscarGarcia por tu tiempo y consejos..Sos un groso.